# Spark Structured Streaming from Files on S3/Disk - add batch filename to records/lines?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am implementing a spark structured streaming application that processes webserver log files from a folder on disk or perhaps S3. 
Spark Structured Streaming fits the use case almost perfectly, with one wrinkle.
The filenames in the folder also contain the machine name eg. like:

/**node1**_20181101.json.gz

/**node1**_20181102.json.gz

/**node2**_20181101.json.gz

/**node3**_20181102.json.gz

/**node4**_20181102.json.gz

...and so on.

A (simplified) version of the source looks something like this ( I would turn the below to a continuous stream with windowing etc):

```
val inputDF = spark.read
  .option("codec", classOf[GzipCodec].getName)
  .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1.toString)
  .json(config.directory)
  .transform { ds =>
      logger.info(ds.inputFiles)
      ds
}.foreach(println(_))
```

I would like to transform the batch and add the node ID from the filename to each record line, - I can't seem to see any kind of an *onBatch* trigger that I could use to enrich the record schema with the node ID from the file name.

I have looked at the following and nothing seems to fit:
[FileStreamSource][https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/spark-structured-streaming/spark-sql-streaming-FileStreamSource.html#metadataLog]

Unfortunately getting a handle on the machine name from the file name is key to the analytics I do later, and I have no control over how the logs are populated

Any clues?

Comment: Do you want to get access to the file name in `transform` method?